# Is it possible to make Eclipse RCP part tabs trapeziform?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is there a way to draw custom Part tabs shape in an Eclipse RCP application (make it trapeziform, for instance) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement [custom presentation](http://bit.ly/lSCo9N) and render tabs as you like. Also see [Extended Presentation Plugin](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/skins/index.html).